# Windows Service and MVC communication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-services

I have a windows service (C#) that is getting data from other services, processing that data as saving it on the database.

Now I have monitoring application (C# Windows Forms) that monitors the windows service via TCP and xml messages.

But now I want to change my monitor app to MVC 4 web application.

My problem is how can I send notifications from my windows services to the each current client in my MVC application?  The clients may be outside the internal network.

Can someone point me to the best approach?

Thanks
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

You have already done much work:

> Now I have monitoring application (C# Windows Forms) that monitors the
>   windows service via TCP and xml messages.

Pass your messages to the an web service that will be accessible by your MVC 4 web application clients.

you need interface between an windows service and the web application which is either a WCF  service or Web Service. You can not access windows service in MVC4 application. If they are same machine or the location of *XML message* file is known and accessible to you then you can directly consume those in your MVC application.

otherwise the path will be **Win Service -> WebService/WCF Service -> MVC4 application**